# Delphi 10.3 Android Remote Service crash when binding

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I tried to build an APP with a remote service, and the service will communicate to other APP that I would like to check it still running.
I reference the [FMX.Remote Service Demo Sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/FMX.Remote_Service_Demo_Sample) create a Multi-Device project and a Android Remote Service project, and add some code to create RemoteServiceConnection and call BindService procedure.
But APP crash when it call BindService, then I tried to build Sample but also crash when I press Bind button.
I build the Sample on Mi Pad 4, Oppo R9sk, HUAWEI MediaPad M5 lite, and Mi 6, are all the same result, and Mi 6 report the message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.embarcadero.AppRemoteHost-EOCjVTj9dNHejm_JDi44nw==/base.apk"], 
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com/embarcadero.AppRemoteHost-EOCjVT9dNHejm_JDi44nw==/lib/arm, 
/data/app/com.embarcadero.AppRemoteHost-EOCjVTj9dNHejm_JDi44nw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, 
/system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libProxyAndroidService.so"  
at
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLirary0(Runtime.java:1012)
  at java.land.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following code to inside **defaultConfig** of project-level **build.gradle** file.

```
ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not use Android Studio, and there is no build.gradle file in Delphi project folder.